# Gracefully killing selenium driver throws errors python

Tags: python, selenium, urllib

I am working with selenium with chromedriver as part of an object

```
class WebDriver():
  def __init__(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('drivers/chromedriver')
  def close(self):
    self.driver.close()
    self.driver.quit()
  def do_something(self):
    # some complicated javascript scraping

def main():
  wd = WebDriver()
  try:
    wd.do_something()
  finally:
    wd.close()
```

This is a toy example. It won't reproduce the error. The actual logic is too complicated to reproduce.

Now, if this program exits early, like if I keyboard interrupt, then I get a whole spew of errors along the lines of:

```
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f91598a9e80>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused

01/03/2022 11:23:31 PM urllib3.connectionpool WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f9c28303a30>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused')': /session/830c7c4101afeb0b492a80212521e80a/window
```

However, these errors are **not** present if I do not have the finally clause (that is, I don't close the driver). It seems like if I do a keyboard interrupt, the driver is already closed and calling .close() and .quit() is whats throwing the error.

At a high level, can someone provide an explanation for why this occurs? Why would the keyboard interrupt within the **do_something()** function close the driver?

Comment: the close() method doesn't quit the driver....  it closes the current browser tab/window.  Some drivers will also quit if that's the last open tab/window.  (different browsers used to differ with this behavior, but not sure about currently...)  You'll want to use quit() method which should close the browser (all open windows/tabs) and dispose of the driver.  It's always a good idea to check if driver=null before quitting... (webdriver can crash) and check/catch exceptions.

Comment: The 'connection refused' error you are seeing there happens when the browser has closed, but the webdriver is still trying to send it commands.